# How to display a set of images in windows phone 8,8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

How can I display a set of scrollable images that I have in Bitmap Format or in List< BitmapImage > and allow user to select one of them.

I have BitmapImage in a List,  here is the code snippet

**Page.XAML**

```
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ImageList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"> 
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding BitmapImage}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

**Page.cs** Code -

```
displayimageslist = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Pro_Images"] as List<BitmapImage>;
        ImageList.ItemsSource = displayimageslist;
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Otherwise it sounds like you're just asking us to do it for you.

Comment: Make a list of images with there "path" , Bitmap and use that list as itemsource of your longlistSelectot control with Image control in datatemplate. and then bind image control source property to your "path", bitmapimage property of list. Too much but it is what you need

Comment: Apologies for not sharing my code. (Edited in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding this as an answer so that other got helped :)

Your List is list of BitmapImage class so you have use this directly as binding.
In your case your are trying to bind a property if BitmapImage Type that is not present anywhere so your image control not able to find its source.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ImageList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"> 
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
```